# Undesirable lines with multi rows in tables

Tags: tables, multirow

I'd like to get your help with a table where I'm using multi rows. It appears lines from rows, it's undesirable.
Also I have a weird alignment of the text in cells, title in 6th row isn't centered. I attached a figure to depict.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{New}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
 \caption{Title}
 \centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{30mm} |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{30mm} |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{30mm} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{TEXT}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{text} & \multirow{2}{*}{text}\\
\hline
\center text\newline text & \center Meses\newline text& \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{TEXT} & TEXT\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Text} & \multirow{3}{*}{text text text text text text text text text text text text}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{60mm}|}{\textbf{TITLE}\newline Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text} & \\
\hline
 & \textbf{TITLE}\newline Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

[image: fig]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `\centering`  not `center`. Also `\cline{<starting column> - <ending column>}` can be used to draw fragments of lines. However, I did not fully understand what you have in mind. Some more clarity is needed if this has to be improved further:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h]
 \caption{Title}
 \centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{30mm} |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{30mm} |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{30mm} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{TEXT}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{text} & \multirow{3}{*}{text}\\
\cline{1-2}
 text  &  Meses & \\
  text  &  text& \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{TEXT} & TEXT\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Text} & \multirow{9}{*}{\parbox{30mm}{text text text text text text text text text text text text}}\\
\cline{1-2}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{TITLE}} & \\
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{60mm}|}{Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text} & \\\cline{1-2}
 & \textbf{TITLE} & \\
 & Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also was working on that, yes, I got it. Thanks a lot. But I have a long text in the right bottom cell, it isn't controlled with column width, please how can I fix it, I've just changed the code.

Comment: @Isai See if it is ok now.

Comment: I forgot it, the trick, using `\parbox`. Thanks.